# Get a similar string a discharge the rest

Tags: javascript, regex

wonder if you could help me out with some Javascript. I have a string that is log message, and i'm waniting to grab a section out of this log and display that on it's own

eg.(bear in mind the log section is not case sesitive and any letter can be any case, also could be placed anywhere withing the string)

**$LOG: 08880xbpnd $
fhdsafidsfsd
df
sd
fsd
f
sd
fsd**

thats the orignal log, Im wanting to grab the 08880xbpnd and get rid of the rest? how can this be done in javascript?

edit

if this is any help i have this regex in perl that grabs the log somewhere else

/(?i)\$LOG:\s*(none|(temp(GD|MD)(.\d{1,2}){4}))\s*\$/

basically what ever in between $LOg: and $ i want to grab and exclude any white space that value in between could be anything or that above

Comment: Can you explain the format that you expect for '08880xbpnd' string?

Comment: Does the string that you want to display always appear after $LOG:(blank space) ? and does the string you want to display always end with a blank space?

Comment: if this is any help i have this regex in perl that grabs the log somewhere else

/(?i)\$LOG:\s*(none|(temp(GD|MD)(\.\d{1,2}){4}))\s*\$/

Comment: @Matthew, Your perl regex only matches a subset of the possible strings that can appear between the "$LOG:" and the "$". Do you want the javascript regex to grab everything, or mimic the perl version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use this regular expression:

```
/\$LOG:([^$]+)\$/i
```

So:

```
"$LOG: 08880xbpnd $ fhdsafidsfsd df sd fsd f sd fsd".match(/\$LOG:([^$]+)\$/i)
```

Comment: Agreed! That is a better Regex than the one I presented. +1 :-)

Comment: Yours is the only regex that's case-insensitive, as per the OP's requirements, so +1 for you ;)

Comment: Although you missed out the fact that it needs to exclude whitespace.

Comment: You can trim those afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Call the function with a sample input string.
  GetMyLog("$LOG: 08880xbpnd $ fhdsafidsfsd df sd fsd f sd fsd");

  function GetMyLog(fullString)
  {
    // Create a Regex object. We want to capture all word-like characters within the $LOG and ending $
    // This assumes that there will not be any more "$" characters in the trailing string.
    var reg = /\$LOG:\s*([\w]+)\s*\$/;

    // If the match attempt was successful, we need to get the second value in the array returned by the match.
    if (fullString.match(reg))
    {
      alert(reg.exec(fullString)[1]);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Yours is the only regex that excludes whitespace, as per the OP's requirements, so +1 for you ;)

Comment: Although you missed out the fact that it needs to be case-insensitive.

Comment: Thanks for the vote, @Luke! My stress in this particular answer was to write the code in JS, rather than perfect the Regex. Great observation, though! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Matthew,

the following regex should give you anything between **$LOG:** and **$** in backreference **\1**

```
\$LOG:(.*?)\$
```

Comment: sorry but how would you call that in javascript?

Comment: I don't know javascript but I guess you could do the same with this expression as is outlined in the excepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I won't use regex, your case is simple and, maybe, using substring you can obtain a gain in speed.

Try using something like this:

```
function getToken(logline, startTag, endTag) {
  return logline.substring(startTag.length,logline.indexOf(endTag,1));
}
```

new version in response of a comment:

```
function getToken(logline, startTag, endTag) {
  result =""; 
  if ( logline.indexOf(startTag)>=0) 
    result= logline.substring(startTag.length,logline.indexOf(endTag,1));
  return result;  
}
```

Comment: this will not work if the $log: tag is not present within the log

Comment: Oh, in your question there are any hints (at least i missed them) 
that the loglines can have different formats